# How to truncate React Natives textInput

Tags: reactjs, react-native, truncate

Need to truncate the textInput with "..." at the end.
for Text component it is doable by just adding `numberOfLines={1}` prop, seems that it is not the case with textInput. How to add the truncation? right now the text goes on endlessly and the input container is scrollable horizontally.

```
export function Input() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <TextInput
        numberOfLines={1}
        style={{ backgroundColor: "red"}}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export function Input() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <TextInput
        numberOfLines={1}
        style={{ backgroundColor: "red"}}
        value={ something.length >= 30?something.slice(0,30)+"...":something }
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: you can manage this inside value